# Why is Crystal Reports Query so slow?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have many Crystal Reports to the same database. Some execute quickly given the same date parameters and many fields are the same as well as the tables they access. One of my reports used to run quickly is now running very slow and I can see it looking through all the records - represented in the bottom `0 of 100000` til it finds records. I have no idea what I may have changed to make it do this. Some reports still run fast and some do not. These findings are consistent with the reports I am talking about. Does anyone know why setting might be causing this?

I have tried looking for any subtle differences in them - I cannot see anything. Many of them where clones from the original(still works fast).

In my CR book in the performance section it states if the where clause can not be translated it will be ignored and for the process of all records - which is what this looks like - though I have a valid where clause when I check it in the report.

`Use Indexes Or Server For Speed` is checked. All other setting in Report Options as identical.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some troubleshoot:

- Try run your query directly on db and see how long it takes.
- Is there any business logic added in your report.
- May be also try to put same query in fresh report and see if it takes similar time.
- Also try debug your application and see if some part of your code making your report to show slow.
- Are you running it on local db or on some server.
- Also if you can share your query, so I can take a look.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: thanks. I have both reports open in Crystal Reports 11, both use the same date range, one executes in less than a second, the other takes more then 2 minutes and I can see the counter on this one and not the other. The reports are using different logins, but still hit the same DB. The only difference with the logins are access to different tables. Business logic meaning? Remote server. They do not want me showing the query. Essentially they are the same for these two reports - so I was comparing apples to apples.

Comment: try putting the same login in other report and see if it works faster. Business logic means, there can be additional logic included in report like calculated fields, some formatting logic, if else on some fields, etc. Also check by creating new fresh report to troubleshoot if it takes same time. Also just use Server name in connection string as "Server=np:server\instance", let me know if it helps..

Comment: Yes, both have Business Login in them, mainly the same - the new report might a few subtle differences. The big take-home point is that this worked fine one day, since then it has been slow like this. I have no idea what I did to make that change. To rebuild from scratch would take much time - maybe something I have to try - not looking forward to that. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: is this count a representation of it looking thru records on the server or CR processing it based on the business logic?

Comment: I got it working be rebuilding the entire report. During my journey I found I could use less groups than previously and that may have ultimately fixed it. Thanks for your time and comments.